# Java android regex groups return with null

Tags: java, android, regex, string, response

So when I use `regex` replace in **pc** Java it works fine.

But when I do it with `Android Java` all responses that are `null` return with null.

How can I remove the null response without doing another replace, or doing a while loop with the `m.group(0);` ?

**Example:**

```
String test = "&lt;test&gt;";
test = test.replaceAll("&lt;([^!])(.*?)(|(\\s)\\b(.*?)(|(&#61;)((\".*?\")|(\\'.*?\\')))(|(\\s)\\b(.*?)(|(&#61;)((\".*?\")|(\\'.*?\\')))))&gt;", "&lt;<span class=\"tag\">$1$2</span>$4<span class=\"att\">$5</span>$7<span class=\"par\">$8</span>$12<span class=\"att\">$13</span>$15<span class=\"par\">$16</span>&gt;");
```

The **response** is:

```
&lt;<span class="tag">test</span>&gt;
```

As it should be, but when I do it in `android` it **returns** with:

```
&lt;<span class="tag">test</span>null<span class="att">null</span>null<span class="par">null</span>t2<span class="att">t3</span>t5<span class="par">t6</span>&gt;
```

please any one give the suggestion to me

Comment: i actually got `&lt;<span class="tag">test</span><span class="att"></span><span class="par"></span><span class="att"></span><span class="par"></span>&gt;` in oracle java 8

Comment: Thats what I was saying, it seems to work fine in normal java until you hit android java

Comment: I suggest changing all unnecessary capturing groups into non-capturing ones.

Comment: The issue with doing that is the replace wont work correctly

Comment: Adjust the replacement pattern. I cannot make my Android Studio work for the time being, my idea is to lower the number of capturing groups to less than 10. OR better - use named capturing groups (`(p)` => `(?<first>p)`, etc.). BTW, in Java, I [get these results](https://ideone.com/pt06ar).

Comment: Another idea: you need to check if the group matched, and if not, discard the replacement for the group. Do it with a `Matcher#appendReplacement`.

Comment: I cant do much about lowering the number of captures due to how it works sadly. Ill try out the naming and look into Matcher